# Create a file in c#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CreateFile
{

    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter the File name:");
            string filename = Console.ReadLine (); 
            System.IO.File.Create(@"G:\New folder (5)\" + filename);            
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: which type of file are u creating?

Comment: you can type any file extention like .txt .exe

Comment: What's your question???

Comment: sorry its not a question........i just uploaded that's all

Comment: @anugrahsp what do you mean it's not a question? It has to be a question, that's the format of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this possible way:

```
using System; using System.IO;

namespace CreateFile {

class MainClass
{

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter the File name:");
        string filename = Console.ReadLine (); 
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"G:\New folder (5)\" + filename + ".txt");
        //You can use any extension to create respective file.
                StreamWriter sw;

                if (!fi.Exists)
                {
                    using (FileStream fs = fi.Create())
                    {

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wait, who done downvote!!! plz consider giving atleast a comment on it!! don't be offensive

Comment: Not downvoter, but answer could be improved with `using`. See example usage here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Dear @weston, I see no difference in link u have posted and my answer!

Comment: Sorry there are two examples on MSDN, I meant the second.